# PHP: pass a file to a function, without echoing into html

Tags: javascript, php, json, function, file

I'm learning php and I'm trying to read a file (located on the server) and pass its content to a js function. So far what i did:

utils.php

```
<?php
function readFile($path)
{
    return file_get_contents($path);
}
<?php>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php 
require_once filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, "DOCUMENT_ROOT", FILTER_SANITIZE_URL) . "/app/php/head.php"; 
define("BASE_PATH", "/home/mark/resources/");
?>
<body>   
    <div id="editor"></div>

    <script>
        var container = document.getElementById("editor");
        var options = {};
        var editor = new JSONEditor(container, options);

        <?php $text = readFile(constant("BASE_PATH") . "myFile.json"); ?>
        editor.setText(<?php echo $text ?>);            
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It actually explicitly print into the HTML the content of the file, which is not what I want of course. I thought the it should be enough:

```
editor.setText(<?php $text ?>);
```

but this line does nothing... 
What is the correct syntax to pass the content of `$text` to the function `setText()` without echoing into HTML?

Comment: what does `$text` look like? What does `JSONEditor.setText()` expect as param? A string or a js-object?

Comment: When you check the source code received in your browser, how does the `editor.setText(...)` line looks like? Is it valid javascript?

Comment: @Jeff both are strings as far as I understand. Of course the content of `$text` should be a JSON string.

Comment: @Progman: I see all the content of `$text` i.e. `{"id": "abc", "data": "blablabla"}`. I guess it isn't recommendable to have the content of the variable in plain text into HTML.

Comment: I'd go with [editor.set()](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/blob/master/docs/api.md#jsoneditorsetjson) and use the json as object: `var json=<?php echo $text; ?>;` then `editor.set(json);`

Comment: [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile) is a core php function. You can't have possibly declared your own / and you're not loading it here. Therefore it will just spit out the raw text at the function call instead of assigning it to $text.

Comment: _or_ if you want to use setText put the json in single quotes. Which of course could be troublesome if the json contains `'` somehwere.

Comment: And I assume you have to quote the json string like `editor.setText('<?php echo $text ?>');`

Comment: @Jeff: it works both ways, but I still see all the content of `$text` in my HTML file...